# why is my hash value changing to false

Tags: ruby, hashtable

I was wondering why when I enter this...;

```
2.0.0-p247 :046 > @possible_places
 => {:a1=>nil, :a2=>nil, :a3=>nil} 
2.0.0-p247 :047 > @possible_places[:a1]
 => nil 
2.0.0-p247 :048 > @possible_places[:a1]=nil?
 => false
```

Why does it return false?  Shouldn't it return true?  Saying that the value is in fact nil?
Furthermore, it replaces the nil value with the false value as such.  Can anyone please explain to a newb?

```
2.0.0-p247 :049 > @possible_places
 => {:a1=>false, :a2=>nil, :a3=>nil} 
2.0.0-p247 :050 > @possible_places[:a1]
 => false
```

Comment: Please use the appropriate language tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the reason :

```
self.nil? # => false
@possible_places = {:a1=>nil, :a2=>nil, :a3=>nil} 
@possible_places[:a1] # => nil
@possible_places[:a1]=nil? # => false
```

In the line `@possible_places[:a1]=nil?`, you called `#nil?` on the top level object `main`.`@possible_places[:a1]=nil?` - it actually means `@possible_places[:a1]=self.nil?`.On the top level `self` is `main`,on which you called `#nil?` method.As `main` object is not `nil`,thus `false` value has been assigned to the key `:a1` of your Hash.You should call it as below :

```
self.nil? # => false
@possible_places = {:a1=>nil, :a2=>nil, :a3=>nil} 
@possible_places[:a1] # => nil
@possible_places[:a1].nil? # => true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am still kind of confused about what you are saying with calling on top level object but you are on the right path I am sure, so I will check-mark your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As you think it should return "true" indicates that you are using the wrong operator. One equal sign (=) is used to set values of the left-hand value. Not to test for equality. If you want to test for equality, use the == operator.

```
@possible_places[:a1] == 1
# Test if @possible_places[:a1] is equal to 1 (False)

@possible_places[:a1] = 1
# Set possible_places[:a1] to 1 and return 1

@possible_places[:a1] == 1
# Test if @possible_places[:a1] is equal to 1 (True)

p nil? #=> false (See Arup Rakshit's answer to understand why)
@possible_places[:a1]=nil? # Set value to nil? or false, and return that value.
```

So, in order to test if your hash is nil you need to do one of the following?

```
@possible_places[:a1]=nil # Set hash to nil
@possible_places[:a1].nil?   # true
@possible_places[:a1] == nil # true
```